# Best practise to upload image to cloudinary in React Native?

Tags: react-native, cloudinary

What is the best method to upload image in a react native app to cloudinary API?. Should I install their SDK from https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary and use it inside the app after installing. Wont it cause any problems after compiling to apk?

Or should I use the manual way? With the `fetch` api in react native and sent a post request to the cloudinary API? Isn't that a bit too much work and at the same time not so secure, because API keys are exposed right? Whats your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the React Native SDK is currently unavailable, it is recommended to use the [direct call to the upload Rest API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_rest_api) as implemented at the client-side of your application (see [sample implementation in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-flower-8tynf?file=/src/App.js)). And you could pass the Cloudinary account parameters from your server-side code to your frontend as an option to manage the credentials.